# Piranha CMS: base class for content types

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, piranha-cms

I have several types of pages. But they have the same regions with settings.
The question is as follows. Is it possible to define a base class with common regions for inheritance organization? So as not to define the same thing in different classes manually.

Has no one ever wondered? Suppose I have 4 content types of pages. But they all have, say, one StringField for some purpose. Now one have to declare this field in every page class, instead of making a base class for all these types. Piranha uses an intermediate GenericPage class to organize inheritance. I don't understand how to implement a base class for content types. Or I don't know something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use normal c# inheritance.

My base class

```
public class PageBase : Page<PageBase>
{
    public class CoverRegion
    {
        [Field]
        public StringField CoverText { get; set; }
        [Field]
        public ImageField CoverImg { get; set; }
    }
    
    [Region]
    public CoverRegion Cover { get; set; }

}
```

Then the class that inherits

```
[PageType(Title = "Inherited Content")]
[ContentTypeRoute(Title = "Default", Route = "page-content")]
public class PageContent : PageBase
{
    [Region]
    public StringField Header { get; set; }
}
```

Remember a region can not only contain one property, must have more.  If there is only one property then set the region attribute on the property instead of field